# Exception while using Html.Action in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Few words about a project.
There are the Main web application (asp.net mvc) and "plugins". Plugin is a asp.net mvc project contains controllers and views.
I am using `RazorGenerator` to make it works.
Im Home view using this link:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("User Workspace", "Index", "Workspace/Workspace")</li>
```

it calls WorkspaceController from my UserWorkspace assembly (Workspace area). It works correctly.
Workspace view contains:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Workspace";
}

<h2>User worspace</h2>
<div>
    TreePlugin:<br />
    @{
        Html.Action("Index", "Plugins/GeObjectTree"); // without this code works fine
    }
</div>
```

I need to render in workspace a plugin's view calling GeObjectTreeController (Plugins area) but this code raise an exception.

```
The controller for path '/Workspace/Workspace' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

Probably exception rises becouse GeObjectTreeController placed in another assembly? Or may be I need to configure some routes or namespaces?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Html.Action("Index", "GeObjectTree", new {area = "Plugins"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use as shown below

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("User Workspace", "Index", "Workspace",  new { area = "Workspace"}, null )</li>

Html.Action("Index", "GeObjectTree",  new {area = "Plugins"}, null)
```